# integrating vector of one variable in r

Tags: r, integration, vectorization, numerical-integration

I'm looking for a way to properly integrate my function:

```
lik = function(par, x){
  cl = c()
  for(i in 1:ncluster){
    sub = c() 
    for(j in 1:nsub){ 
      times = t[[i]][[j]]
      m = c(1,t[[i]][j],t(cov[[i]][j,])) 
      repmat = cbind(1,1:t[[i]][j],matrix(rep(cov[[i]][j,], times),times, 3,byrow=T))
      sub[j] = d[[i]][j]*m%*%c(par[-5],x)-sum(log((1+exp(repmat%*%c(par[-5],x))))) 
    }  
    cl[i] = sum(sub) 
  } 
  return(exp(cl))  
}
```

function `lik` (which is likelihood) takes `x`, vector `par` of length 5, and yields a vector of likelihood at `x` at each cluster. For example,

```
> lik(1:5,1)
[1] 4.640101e-30 3.632315e-44 5.348611e-09 1.121790e-27 1.696704e-98
> #number of clusters=5
```

I want to integrate out `x` so that I can obtain the vector of marginalized pdf at each cluster, but function `integrate` or any other numerical integration packages are only capable of integrating scalar function. I've searched questions relating to this, and maybe Vectorization is the key to solving this problem, but I just do not know how.

I will really appreciate if you can give me any help. Thanks

Comment: Please format your code finely so that other people can read it easily and you can get your best answer.

Answer (score 1):

Typically I recommend converting a function of 2 variables to a function of one variable prior to integrating as follows.

```
myfunc <-function(x,y){ stuff}

intfunc <-function(x){myfunc(x,y)}

integrate(intfunc,x, etc)
```